# How to sequentially set bits

Tags: python

When the `if` statement is `true` I want to sequentially set every bit in the left shift operation one at a time rather than setting all bits at once. Any idea on how I could implement this?

```
 if (reg_test == arduino_reg7.value):

        Reg_Value |= (0x1A << 20)
```

Comment: Not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve. Can you give an example of what Reg_Value might look like before and after the bitwise or operation

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, you want to have `Reg_Value' be set to each of these in succession:

```
0bxxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
0bxxx1_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
0bxx01_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
0bx101_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
0b1101_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx_xxxx
```

Where the `'x'` bits are left unmodified

I would suggest:

```
if (reg_test == arduino_reg7.value):
    bval = 0x1A
    for i in range(20,28):
        Reg_Value |= (bval << 20) & (1 << (i+1))
```

This allows for any byte value (`bval`) to be placed in bits 20-27 one bit at a time, in ascending order. Any higher-order bits are also left unchanged.

You could simplify the `(1 << (i+1))` to `(1 << i)` by changing the range to `range(21, 29)`. But bits are typically numbered from 0, and this affects bits 20-27, not 21-28.

You could also change it to `(2 << i)` and leave the range, but I think that obscures what you're really doing -- though that's a personal preference. Unless timing is extremely critical, the extra `+1` won't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your value of 0x1A is constant then you could simply create a list where each element represents one of the 3 bits. Then:

```
bits = [0x10 << 20, 0x8 << 20, 0x2 << 20]

if (reg_test == arduino_reg7.value):
  for b in bits:
    Reg_Value |= b
```

If 0x1A is not constant, then you could build your array of bits like this:

```
v = 0x1a # or some other 8-bit value
bits = []
b = 1
while v > 0:
    if v & 1:
        bits.append(b<<20)
    b <<= 1
    v >>= 1
```